# How to create Column C on DF1 using values from DF2 using Column A and B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains employee information such as Name, performance_factor_1 and performance_factor_2 .

I have another dataframe where I get pay based on performance_factor_1 and performance_actor_2.

df1 (Sorry for formatting not sure how to fix it)

```
Name                  pf1       pf2     pf3
Adam                  14.6      8.9     59 
Bob                   13.2      9       75
Charlie               11.1      9.1     89
Dylan                 14.6      9       97
Eric                  11.1      8.8     105
Fedderick             12.5      9.2     69
```

df2
The rows of dataframe 2 are performance_factor_1 and columns are performance_factor_2.

```
pf1     8.8 8.9 9   9.1 9.2
14.6    100 200 300 400 500
13.2    200 300 400 500 600
12.5    300 400 500 600 700
11.1    400 500 600 700 800
```

For df2['pf1'] it extends from 1 to 14 with 1 decimal place. for the columns it goes from 8.8 to 10 with one decimal point. It would be better if I was able to attain the values using a range of sort such as 8.8 -9.2 .  However, for now I am only currently looking for the pay based on exact values.

What I want to do is add a third column pay to df1 such as below if p3 is above 70:
df1

```
Name                  pf1       pf2      pay
Adam                  14.6      8.9      200
Bob                   13.2      9        400
Charlie               11.1      9.1      700
Dylan                 14.6      9        300
Eric                  11.1      8.8      400
Fedderick             12.5      9.2      700
```

What I have tried in terms of coding is:
1) Using a function and then calling it during the loc function below but it kept throwing a "'Series' objects are mutable, thus unhashable" error

```
def indivpay(ttr, csat):
    dude = (indiv.at[ttr, csat])
    return dude
df1.loc[df1['pf3']>=70, 'pay'] =  indivpay(df_outer['pf1'], df_outer['pf2'])
```

2) Getting the pay value in the loc function itself but it kept throwing a "'Series' objects are mutable, thus unhashable" error

```
df_outer.loc[df_outer['# of Closed SRs']>=70, 'Individual Bonus'] =  indiv.at[df_outer['Time to Resolve'], df_outer['CSAT (NSE)'].astype(str)]
```

---

I've fixed a similar problem before using the loc function.However, for that I created column C based on A and B within the same dataframe. I used the below code for that:

```
df.loc[df['Last Resolved Date'].notnull(), 'Duration'] =  (df['Closed Date'] - df['Date Opened'])
```

It was able to fill out the Duration column with the number of days. However, this method does not seem to work for the above mentioned problem.

In the end what I want is for pay to get added to df1 based on pf1 and pf2 only if p3 is above 70.

**EDIT:**
Now is it possible to get the pay using a range of pf1 and pf2

[image]

I created [Using values from df1 to retrieve values from df2 where df2 columns and index contain a range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901523/using-values-from-df1-to-retrieve-values-from-df2-where-df2-columns-and-index-co) for this second question.

Comment: the df you putout is the expected df? I ask because in column `pay`,even for value less that 70 in pf3, you have values from df2

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to take the values out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can create new column with [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
#if pf1 is first column, not index
#df2 = df2.set_index('pf1')
df2 = df2.rename(columns=float)

df1['Pay'] = df2.lookup(df1['pf1'], df1['pf2'])
print (df1)
        Name   pf1  pf2  pf3  Pay
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59  200
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  400
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  700
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97  300
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  400
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  700
```

Because working with floats, is possible some values not matched, because accuracy, so possible solution is multiple values by `10` and cast to integers:

```
df3 = df2.rename(index= lambda x: int(x * 10),
                 columns= lambda x: int(float(x) * 10))

df1['Pay'] = df3.lookup(df1['pf1'].mul(10).astype(int), df1['pf2'].mul(10).astype(int))
print (df1)
        Name   pf1  pf2  pf3  Pay
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59  200
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  400
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  700
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97  300
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  400
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  700
```

EDIT:

If possible some values not matched:

```
df3 = df2.rename(index= lambda x: int(x * 10),
                 columns= lambda x: int(float(x) * 10))

out= []
for row, col in zip(df1['pf1'].mul(10).astype(int), df1['pf2'].mul(10).astype(int)):
    try:
        out.append(df3.at[row, col] )
    except KeyError:
        out.append(np.nan)

df1['Pay'] = out
print (df1)
        Name   pf1  pf2  pf3  Pay
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59  200
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  400
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  700
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97  300
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  400
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  700
```

Last you can assign/create new columns by conditions:

```
df1.loc[df1['pf3']>=70, 'Pay_new'] = df1['Pay']
print (df1)
        Name   pf1  pf2  pf3  Pay  Pay_new
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59  200      NaN
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  400    400.0
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  700    700.0
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97  300    300.0
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  400    400.0
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  700      NaN
```

Comment: `df2 = df2.rename(columns=float)` throws error since text `pf1` is present as one column header.

Comment: @SH-SF - added to code `df2 = df2.set_index('pf1')`

Comment: I tried using 
`df1['Pay'] = df2.lookup(df1['pf1'], df1['pf2'])` 
but I keep getting 
    KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found'
I have edited the df2 to include values from 14.0,13.9 all the way to 0.1,0 Since I have many employee names and various pf1 values

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - Do you test second solution with `df3 = df2.rename(index= lambda x: int(x * 10),
                 columns= lambda x: int(float(x) * 10))`?

Comment: Thanks so much!! The "If some values not matched" section was the one that did it for me. Copy pasted and replaced everything. No I am going to try and understand everything. 

I am not sure if this should be asked here or new question but is it possible to do something with a range of values for both pf1 and 2? I'll edit the question and show you

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - Sure, if still something unclear, let me know.

Comment: I edited the Question again. Sorry I didnt ask for this at first. I was frustrated at not being able to do the lookup at first

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - Not sure if understand, can you create new question - input data, expcted output and code, what you try?

Comment: Ive added the second question link to this question. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

First use `pf1` as an index of `df2`. If the type of the `columns` is `str` convert it to `float`. After use `pf1` y `pf2` as an index of `df1`.

```
df2.set_index('pf1',inplace=True) #if it not is index
df2.columns=[float(key) for key in df2.columns] #only if it is str
df1.set_index(['pf1','pf2'],inplace=True)
```

this makes it possible for you to assign values ​​to the `pay` column easily with [pandas.DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df1['pay']=df2.stack()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1=df1.reindex(columns=['Name','pf1','pf2','pf3','pay'])
df1['new_pay']=df1['pay'].where(df1['pf3']>70)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
        Name   pf1  pf2  pf3  pay  new_pay
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59  200      NaN
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  400    400.0
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  700    700.0
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97  300    300.0
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  400    400.0
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  700      NaN
```

Comment: I tested every step of the way and after I do
`df1['pay']=df2.stack()`
I get a pay column filled with NaN values