# Using values from df1 to retrieve values from df2 where df2 columns and index contain a range of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have a dataframe that contains employee information such as Name, performance_factor_1 and performance_factor_2 .

I have another dataframe where I get pay based on performance_factor_1 and performance_actor_2.

df1

```
Name                  pf1       pf2     pf3
Adam                  14.6      8.9     59 
Bob                   13.2      9       75
Charlie               11.1      9.1     89
Dylan                 14.6      9       97
Eric                  11.1      8.8     105
Fedderick             12.5      9.2     69
```

df2
The rows of dataframe 2 are performance_factor_1 and columns are performance_factor_2.

```
pf1       8.8-8.9  9.0-9.2 9.3-9.4  9.5-9.6  9.7-10
11.1 to 14  100      200    300       400     500
8.1 to 11   200      300    400       500     600
6.1 to 8    300      400    500       600     700
below 6     400      500    600       700     800
```

What I want to do is add a third column pay to df1 such as below if p3 is above 70:
df1

```
Name                  pf1       pf2      pay
Adam                  14.6      8.9      200
Bob                   13.2      9        400
Charlie               11.1      9.1      700
Dylan                 14.6      9        300
Eric                  11.1      8.8      400
Fedderick             12.5      9.2      700
```

What I have tried in my earlier post [How to create Column C on DF1 using values from DF2 using Column A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888040/how-to-create-column-c-on-df1-using-values-from-df2-using-column-a-and-b) is to physically list out 14,13.9 --- 0.1,0 for the pf1 index and 
list out 8.8, 8.9 -- 10 and then using lookup to match the exact pf1 and pf2 values. However, that is not fit for the long term in case df2 changes in which there will be a ton of manual work related to changing most values of df2.

This is the code I tried to use for in the exact value match lookup method:

```
df_outer.reset_index(inplace=True)

df3 = indiv.rename(index= lambda x: int(x * 10),
                 columns= lambda x: int(float(x) * 10))
out= []
for row, col in zip(df_outer['TTR'].mul(10).astype(int), df_outer['CSAT (NSE)'].mul(10).astype(int)):
    try:
        out.append(df3.at[row, col] )
    except KeyError:
        out.append(np.nan)

df_outer['Pay'] = out

df_outer.loc[df_outer['# of Closed SRs']>=70, 'Pay_new'] = df_outer['Pay']
print (df_outer)
```

EDIT:
So in the end, I have the below output. But it was using df2(old) and I want to use df2(new) to get my output

```
       Name   pf1  pf2  pf3  Pay  
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59  NaN    
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  400    
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  700    
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97  300    
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  400    
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  NaN
```

Previousy,my df2(old) was like this

```
pf1     8.8 8.9 9   9.1 9.2
14.6    100 200 300 400 500
13.2    200 300 400 500 600
12.5    300 400 500 600 700
11.1    400 500 600 700 800
```

Now I want my df2(new) to be like this

```
pf1       8.8-8.9  9.0-9.2 9.3-9.4  9.5-9.6  9.7-10
11.1 to 14  100      200    300       400     500
8.1 to 11   200      300    400       500     600
6.1 to 8    300      400    500       600     700
below 6     400      500    600       700     800
```

Edit 2: 
My df 2 looks like in this in the csv:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you already have the `Pay` column, and you want to add a `Pay_new` column base on `pf3>=70`?

Comment: I edited it. Hope you are able to understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible create `IntervalIndex` by [`IntervalIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples.html) in columns and index in `df2` DataFrame and then change lookup with [`IntervalIndex.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.get_loc.html):

First test:

```
print (df2.columns)
Index(['8.8-8.9', '9.0-9.2', '9.3-9.4', '9.5-9.6', '9.7-10'], dtype='object')

print (df2.index)
Index(['11.1 to 14', '8.1 to 11', '6.1 to 8', 'below 6'], dtype='object', name='pf1')
```

---

```
c = [(float(x[0]), float(x[1])) for x in df2.columns.str.split('-')]
i = [(0, float(x[0].split()[1])) if 'below' in x[0] else (float(x[0]), float(x[1])) 
                               for x in df2.index.str.split(' to ')]

print (i)
[(11.1, 14.0), (8.1, 11.0), (6.1, 8.0), (0, 6.0)]

print (c)
[(8.8, 8.9), (9.0, 9.2), (9.3, 9.4), (9.5, 9.6), (9.7, 10.0)]
```

---

```
df2.columns = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(c, closed='both')    
df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(i, closed='both')
print (df2)
              [8.8, 8.9]  [9.0, 9.2]  [9.3, 9.4]  [9.5, 9.6]  [9.7, 10.0]
[11.1, 14.0]         100         200         300         400          500
[8.1, 11.0]          200         300         400         500          600
[6.1, 8.0]           300         400         500         600          700
[0.0, 6.0]           400         500         600         700          800

out= []
for row, col in zip(df1['pf1'], df1['pf2']):
    try:
        out.append(df2.iat[df2.index.get_loc(row), df2.columns.get_loc(col)])
    except KeyError:
        out.append(np.nan)

df1['Pay'] = out
print (df1)
        Name   pf1  pf2  pf3    Pay
0       Adam  14.6  8.9   59    NaN
1        Bob  13.2  9.0   75  200.0
2    Charlie  11.1  9.1   89  200.0
3      Dylan  14.6  9.0   97    NaN
4       Eric  11.1  8.8  105  100.0
5  Fedderick  12.5  9.2   69  200.0
```

Comment: I did up to 
`df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(i, closed='both')`
 but am facing IndexError:List index out of range error

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - Data are confidental ?

Comment: Yeap. Sorry about that. Maybe I can replace some stuff ?

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - ok, what return `i` in real data?

Comment: How would I check? I am fairly new to python and can slightly understand. However, it seems that the problem lies with `c = [(float(x[0]), float(x[1])) for x in df2.columns.str.split('-')]`

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - Can you check `print (i)` ?

Comment: Both name(c) and name(i) is not defined

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - I try explian - I split each value by `to` and then convert both values to floats. Problem is with last value for `below 6` - then split by whitespace - ['bellow', '6'] ans seelct second value `6`. Last add `0`

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - test it after `i = [(0, float(x[0].split()[1])) if 'below' in x[0] else (float(x[0]), float(x[1])) 
                               for x in df2.index.str.split(' to ')]`

Comment: Would it help if I changed the index according to the EDIT 2 in my question?

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - I edit answer, for you it return similar values?

Comment: I also tested it again and it doesn't work even until 
`indiv.columns = pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(c, closed='both')`

Comment: @ShafeekShaik - Answer is edited again, with 4 times print

Comment: I got exactly what I wanted. It works! I even edited the pf1 values and it accepted it and worked with it. Thanks @jezrael